# Error at rotation layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to rotate the whole `FrameLayout`, but it gives me an error:

```
08-13 16:58:28.940: E/AndroidRuntime(22244): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
```

That's the method :

```
private void rotateLayout() {

    FrameLayout frLayout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
    final View view = View.inflate((Context) this, R.layout.testremote, null);
    frLayout.addView(view);

    int w = frLayout.getWidth();
    int h = frLayout.getHeight();

    frLayout.setRotation(270.0f);
    frLayout.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
    frLayout.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)frLayout.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = w;
    lp.width = h;
    frLayout.requestLayout();

}
```

And the `FrameLayout` is already inflated in `onCreate`. I'm not sure if i need to inflate it here too.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Show whole logcat error

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Your for some reason creating layout programatically - I have same problem when layout is created from xml

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
FrameLayout frLayout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
```

Your `frLayout` just created right before `final View view` and you didn't add it to anywhere yet.
-> So of course `frLayout.getLayoutParams()` will return null.
Change `frLayout` to your inflated `frameLayout` in `onCreate`

```
 FrameLayout frLayout = // your inflated frameLayout here.
```